# Como hacer una lista donde se puedan agregar varios registros y guardar todos esas datos?

Tags: php, html

Estoy queriendo hacer un listado para agregar personal que participó en una capacitación y no sé como podría hacer que cuando abra el modal y de en la opcion de **agregar** se vayan agregando a un listado y al haber agregado las personas que participaron a la capacitación pueda guardarlo y me muestre en la tabla de capacitaciones solo el nombre de la capacitación y que al darle editar pueda ver toda esa información que guardé y pues saber como editarla también.

No he podido encontrar como hacer eso, lo único que he logrado es hacer una tabla donde debería aparecer los datos que iría agregando y un modal donde mostraría todo el personal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php 
        include "conexion/db.php";
        $sql = "SELECT a.Id_foto, a.Nombre_em, b.Id_cargo, b.Cargo
                FROM personal as a
                INNER JOIN cargo b on b.Id_cargo = a.Id_cargo";
        $resul = $cone->query($sql);
    ?>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Capacitaciones</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styl.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <link rel=icon href='img/logo-icon.png' sizes="32x32" type="image/png">  </head>
      <body>

    <br>

        <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Listado de personal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="capa" class="col-md-1 control-label">Capacitacion</label>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="capa" placeholder="Escriba la capacitacion" required>

                      </div>


                     </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Buscar personal</h4><br>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar productos" onkeyup="load(1)">
                            </div><br><br>
                          </div>

                          <table id="tabla" border="1" class='tabla_datos'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr id="titulo">
                                <th>Nº Foto</th>
                                <th>Nombre empleado</th>
                                <th>Cargo</th>
                                <th>Comando</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc())  
                            {?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['Id_foto']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['Nombre_em']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['Cargo']; ?></td>
                                    <td><a href="#">Agregar</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php }?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                        <div id="loader" style="position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 55px;  width: 100%;display:none;"></div>
                        <div class="outer_div" ></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal -->

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="datos_factura">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Agregar personal
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Guardar
                            </button>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </form> 

            <div id="resultados" class='col-md-12' style="margin-top:10px"></div>   

            </div>

        </div>      
        </div>
        <hr>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/letras.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/buscar.js"></script>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Primero cree una tabla llamada CAPACITACIONES con los campos que necesita guardar, entre ellos un campo para relacionar la información del empleado (id_empleado). después en su modal poner un formulario con 
 un campo ListMenu (llenado con información de la tabla empleados) en donde aparezca el nombre del empleado y en el valor su ID, ademas de los demás datos a guardar. para después mandarlo al proceso de php donde se ejecute la sentencia SQL con un INSERT para guardar los datos en la tabla CAPACITACIONES. Si despues quiere editarlo tendra que hacer una sentencia SQL UPDATE.

Comment: La tabla de CAPACITACIONES ya la tengo creada al igual que la llave foranea del empleado y dos campos mas que seria el NOMBRE DE LA CAPACITACION y LA FECHA  que se realizo, lo que si no entiendo es que se logro hacer el list menu y tengo 15 personas agregadas y al guardar como se guardaran esos 15 registros

Comment: El listMenu le serviría para seleccionar un solo empleado y guardar la información. Si lo que quiere es guardar los 15 registros en un solo paso, tendría que listar los 15 empleados y poner en el formulario un elemento checkbox con el id_empleado en value, para marcar los empleados que quiere guardar en la tabla de capacitación. para eso tendrá que poner en el nombre que le de al checkbox unos corchetes para indicar que es un array,  algo como name="id_empleado[]" y despues en PHP recorrer el array con un bucle para recuperar esos datos y hacer el INSERT en la tabla.

Comment: Amigo si no es mucha molestia me podrías hacer un mini ejemplo he investigado y solo me sale informacion de combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte donde muestras los datos del empleado es donde pondrías los checkbox, y poder seleccionar a múltiples empleados para registrarlos en una capacitación, pondré el ejemplo a groso modo, (sin entrar en detalles finos). En **insertarDatosSQL.php** es donde harás todo el proceso de insertar los registros en la tabla capacitaciones, tendrás que usar un bucle foreach para sacar la lista (array) de id_empleado y dentro de ese bucle haces el insert.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="insertarDatosSQL.php">
<input type="text" name="capacitacion">
<input type="text" name="fecha">

<?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Id_foto']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Nombre_em']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Cargo']; ?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="id_empleado[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_empleado']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```